# File doesn't show up in git commit tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, dvcs

I have just started using git recently. I am having an issue with viewing my changed files in the git commit tool. I am using visual studio as my development environment. I have couple of projects as localhost and localhost/admin. I did some changes to the files in the both the projects. When I run the git commit tool I can see the changes from the localhost project but cannot see the changes from the localhost/admin project. Any idea why it is behaving like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My other project was redirecting to a different path in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no changes displayed, means that they were not commited.

Possible reasons for that:

1) These are new files and you need to add them to commit separately

2) Files are ignored by git due to .gitignore rules

I would suggest:

1) Use gitk tool to verify what was commited previously. This tool is included in standard git package.

2) Use external tool to do commits (i am not sure how good VS git plugin, but that could help a lot). In my list of personal preferences is git-cola tool. It can let you choose what exactly will go to commit (even by lines of code)

Comment: If I make any changes to the files it should list in git commit tool right?

Comment: @Joshua That depends on tool you use to commit. Some tools are pretty dumb and often do not follow any logic (for example git plugin for WebStorm IDE). As i pointed in my answer i have no idea about Visual Studio git plugin. But i personally gave up using any embedded into IDE plugins and always use external tools. git-cola that i recommended is pretty cool. Just give it a try.

Comment: I am not using any integrated into the IDE. I am using the git commit tool which you get when you right click the folder. Default one I think.

Comment: @Joshua you mean standard Git UI? Then it is not very good tool for that. In that tool you need manually `stage` every file you want to be commited. If you did not stage some files even though these were modified, it will not commit them. Check it using gitk tool (you have it already, if as you said you used Git UI tool). It will show you whole repository history with details what was commited in each single commit.

Comment: I got it sorted. The changes are now showing in the standard git commit tool. My other project was redirecting to a different path in IIS.